# Shifting subtitle start time making a .gif from .mkv in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

following @LordNeckbeard's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027422/convert-avi-to-gif-with-ffmpeg-with-good-quality-and-subtitles/34028269#34028269?newreg=6ec7bd47afd34d0fb908bfc0c4096ec2/%22advice%22), I can add a subtitle track to a gif, however the subtitle track is included in the .mkv file. I can adjust the start time of the input file, but the subtitle track is starting from the beginning.

After generating a palette, the command to create the gif is:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -ss $start_time -t $duration -i video.mkv -i $palette -filter_complex "fps=60,scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos, subtitles=video.mkv [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y "$outputfile"
```

But the subtitle filter isn't shifting to $start_time. Is there a way to specify this in the filter? Or do I need to first extract the subtitle file and edit it to start at the appropriate section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With fast seek, ffmpeg does not decode or **filter** frames till start time is reached. So, when the (subtitles) filter is initiated, it starts from the beginning of the SRT. Switching to slow seek by placing the `ss` and `t` after the input gets you the behaviour you wanted.

```
ffmpeg -v warning -i video.mkv -i $palette -ss $start_time -t $duration -filter_complex "fps=60,scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos, subtitles=video.mkv [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y "$outputfile
```